# Rotate force around Z axis

Tags: force-fields

I'm trying to create a hairline presentation of colliding force fields.

I want an object rotating around Z axis to carry it's force field around.

Is this possible? I see no standard method.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do... an object "to carry its force field around"? My first guess would be you want a force field parented to another object and this should be rotated on Z. So, select force field, Shift + select object, Ctrl + P > _Set Parent to Object_. Then keyframe the Z rotation of the object.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments by @Gordon Brinkmann.

> ... So, select force field, Shift + select object, Ctrl + P > Set Parent to Object. Then keyframe the Z rotation of the object.

Comment: kindly include that comment in your answer. you can use the tools to quote  others.

Comment: Done and done! :)